# How can I speed up calculation of the fixed effects in a GLMM?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I'm doing a simulation study which requires bootstrapping estimates obtained from a generalized linear mixed model (actually, the product of two estimates for fixed effects, one from a GLMM and one from an LMM). To do the study well would require about 1000 simulations with 1000 or 1500 bootstrap replications each time. This takes a significant amount of time on my computer (many days).

`How can I speed up the computation of these fixed effects?`

To be more specific, I have subjects who are measured repeatedly in three ways, giving rise to variables X, M, and Y, where X and M are continuous and Y is binary. We have two regression equations 
$$M=\alpha_0+\alpha_1X+\epsilon_1$$
$$Y^*=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\beta_2M+\epsilon_2$$
where Y$^*$ is the underlying latent continuous variable for $Y$ and the errors are not iid.
The statistic we want to bootstrap is $\alpha_1\beta_2$. Thus, each bootstrap replication requires fitting an LMM and a GLMM. My R code is (using lme4)

```
    stat=function(dat){
        a=fixef(lmer(M~X+(X|person),data=dat))["X"]
        b=fixef(glmer(Y~X+M+(X+M|person),data=dat,family="binomial"))["M"]
        return(a*b)
    }
```

I realize that I get the same estimate for $\alpha_1$ if I just fit it as a linear model, so that saves some time, but the same trick doesn't work for $\beta_2$.

Do I just need to buy a faster computer? :)

Comment: @BR whats the bottle neck here? Basically what's taking time in `Rprof`.

Comment: One way is to just ignore the "mixed" part of the GLMM.  Just fit an ordinary GLM, the estimates won't change much, but their standard errors probably will

Comment: @probabilityislogic. In addition to your remark, I also think, whether answer would differ much depends on the group size and individual behavior in group. As Gelman and Hill say: mixed effects model results would be between pooling and no pooling. (Obv. this is for Bayesian hierarchical models, but mixed models are a classical way of doing the same.)

Comment: @probabilityislogic: That works for LMM, but it seems to fail for GLMM (meaning that I ran models with and without the extra M on the same data and ended up with significantly different results). Unless, of course, there is an error in the implementation of glmer.

Comment: @suncoolsu: the bottleneck is the estimation of the GLMM, which may a couple of seconds (especially with several random effects). But do that 1000*1000 times, and that's 280 hours of computation. Fitting a GLM takes about 1/100 of the time.

Comment: In my specific situation, there are about 50 individuals and each is measured about 10 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should help to specify starting values, though it's hard to know how much. As you're doing simulation and bootstrapping, you should know the 'true' values or the un-bootstrapped estimates or both. Try using those in the `start =` option of `glmer`.

You could also consider looking into the whether the tolerances for declaring convergence are stricter than you need. I'm not clear how to alter them from the `lme4` documentation though.

Answer (score 5):

Two other possibilities too consider, before buying a new computer.

1. Parallel computing - bootstrapping is easy to run in parallel. If your computer is reasonably new, you probably have four cores. Take a look the the [multicore](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/multicore/multicore.html) library in R.
2. Cloud computing is also a possibility and reasonably cheap. I have colleagues that have used the amazon cloud for running R scripts. They found that it was quite cost effective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Somehow, I've overlooked the fact that I have two cores (my computer isn't very new). I should've looked at multicore a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

It could possibly be a faster computer.  But here is one trick which may work.

Generate a simultation of $Y^*$, but only conditional on $Y$, then just do OLS or LMM on the simulated $Y^*$ values.

Supposing your link function is $g(.)$.  this says how you get from the probability of $Y=1$ to the $Y^*$ value, and is most likely the logistic function $g(z)=log \Big(\frac{z}{1-z}\Big)$.

So if you assume a bernouli sampling distribution for $Y\rightarrow Y\sim Bernoulli(p)$, and then use the jeffreys prior for the probability, you get a beta posterior for $p\sim Beta(Y_{obs}+\frac{1}{2},1-Y_{obs}+\frac{1}{2})$.  Simulating from this should be like lighting, and if it isn't, then you need a faster computer.  Further, the samples are independent, so no need to check any "convergence" diagnostics such as in MCMC, and you probably don't need as many samples - 100 may work fine for your case.  If you have binomial $Y's$, then just replace the $1$ in the above posterior with $n_i$, the number of trials of the binomial for each $Y_i$.

So you have a set of simulated values $p_{sim}$.  You then apply the link function to each of these values, to get $Y_{sim}=g(p_{sim})$.  Fit a LMM to $Y_{sim}$, which is probably quicker than the GLMM program.  You can basically ignore the original binary values (but don't delete them!), and just work with the "simulation matrix" ($N\times S$, where $N$ is the sample size, and $S$ is the number of simulations).

So in your program, I would replace the $gmler()$ function with the $lmer()$ function, and $Y$ with a single simultation, You would then create some sort of loop which applies the $lmer()$ function to each simulation, and then takes the average as the estimate of $b$.  Something like 
$$a=\dots$$
$$b=0$$
$$do \ s=1,\dots,S$$
$$b_{est}=lmer(Y_s\dots)$$
$$b=b+\frac{1}{s}(b_{est}-b)$$
$$end$$
$$return(a*b)$$

Let me know if I need to explain anything a bit clearer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it'll take me a bit to digest it (and I already have plans for my Saturday night). It is different enough that it is not clear to me if it gives the same answer as the GLMM approach, but I need to think about it more.